# Adding a header to files Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have 100 files in my directory named dat_comp{1..100}.txt up to 100. I would like to add a header to each of these files so that I have Dat_comp{1..100}.txt. I tried a solution.

```
echo -e "ID\tBMI\tGeno" | cat - dat_comp{1..100}.txt > Comp_dat{1..100}.txt
```

I had an error : -bash: Comp_dat{1..100}.txt: ambiguous redirect

Please what am I doing wrong? I want the output to be 100 files with the header appended and formed into new files with the names Comp_dat{1..100}.txt.

Comment: Think about how the shell expands that: `cat - input1 input2 > output1 output2`. That's ambiguous. In the duplicates, I'd favour the `find -exec` style solutions.

Comment: `xargs` might be part of another practical approach